# Mass operations on Red-Black Trees?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

At my project I need to update/delete/insert a number of RB-Trees very frequently. The thing is updates come in packets of items, like:

100 new items to insert,
100 keys to delete,
and so on

Moreover, the items in each packet are sorted by the same key the tree is built with.

Can I somehow exploit this property of my data to increase update/delete/insert opertions' performance? E.g. may be there is some algo of massive items delete for RB-Tree?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't need specifically RB-trees, but a O(logn) search, I'd suggest using skip lists and just merge existing skip list with a skip list for the incoming "packet".

Comment: +1 for skip lists: an underused data structure with a lot of power.